# Value coerced to &str from &&str has null values on bare metal

Tags: rust, bare-metal

Here is a minimal example:

**lib.rs:**

```rust
#![feature(lang_items)]
#![no_std]

extern crate rlibc;
extern crate libc;

use libc::{c_int, c_char};

#[no_mangle] // just for easier llvm-ir reading
fn foo(baz: &str) -> usize {
    baz.len()
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn main(_argc: c_int, _argv: *const *const c_char) -> c_int {
    let gdb_wait = true; // for debugging with gdb
    while unsafe { core::ptr::read_volatile(&gdb_wait) } {}

    assert_eq!(foo(&"bar_fail"), 0);
    assert_eq!(foo("bar_ok"), 6);

    loop {}
}

// just some functions to run on bare metal.

#[lang = "panic_fmt"]
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn rust_begin_panic(_msg: core::fmt::Arguments, _file: &'static str, _line: u32) -> ! {
    loop {}
}

#[lang = "eh_personality"]
pub extern fn eh_personality() { loop {} }

#[allow(non_snake_case)]
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn _Unwind_Resume() -> ! { loop {} }

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn fmod(_: f64, _: f64) {
    loop {  }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn fmodf(_: f32, _: f32) {
    loop {  }
}
```

Main function is called by asm on qemu-system-x86_64 in 64bit-longmode.

The GDB output from the first call when `&&str` is passed. This doesn't work:

```
(gdb) print baz
$1 = {data_ptr = 0x0, length = 0}
```

The GDB output from the second call when `&str` is passed. This works fine:

```
(gdb) print baz
$2 = {data_ptr = 0xffffffff80133460 <str4498> "bar_oksrc/lib.rsassertion failed: `(left == right)` (left: ``, right: ``)\001gdb_load_rust_pretty_printers.py", length = 6}
```

Here is [a full runnable project](https://github.com/xosmig/xo_os/tree/string_slice_method_problem).

Comment: that sounds a lot like undefined behaviour... on a side-note: there's no need to implement a trait for `&'a str` if all the methods are by reference, you can implement it directly for `str`

Comment: Just for the sake of exactness, those statements (`tmp.test()`, etc...) are contained within a `main` method, right?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. It is quite unclear what `Serial` and `write_str` are.

Comment: @starblue Done.

Comment: Could you `objdump -D <executable>` and paste the relevant things (all the whole thing). I suspect it might be problem with gdb/dwarf interpreting `&str &str` incorrectly, not the code itself. You could try saving `baz.len()` to globals just to confirm.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is solved by editing the linker script. String was placed after bss section in memory. So multiboot filled it with zeros.